# Jquery ajax form array submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a form comment section whereby a user can reply to a comment. Each comment has a form with a reply box. Am getting the comments from the database and running the following loop.

```
@foreach($responses as $response)

<li>{{$response->answer}}</li>

<form action="{{action('DiscussionController@postAnswerQuestion', [$entry_year, $grade_id, $subject_id, $question_id])}}" method="post" id="form1">
<input type="text" name="reply" value="" placeholder="Reply">
<input type="hidden" name="response_id" value="{{$response->id}}">
<input type="submit" name="" value="reply">
 </form>
  @endforeach
```

When I submit the php form using normal PHP it submits just fine but when using jquery ajax and the following code.

```
  var formData = {
        'answer'            : $('input[name=answer]').val(),
        'reply'             : $('input[name=reply]').val(),
        'response_id'       : $('input[name=response_id]').val(),
    };
```

It returns the value of the first input only after some googling I found that I should use serialize and so instead of the above jquery code I used the following

```
        var formData = $('#form1').serialize();
```

But now the values arent being captured and the values are coming to php as null. How should I solve the above problem?

Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Are you passing formData obj to your php page ? If so , do you see formData obj as null or undefined ?

Comment: You have `id="form1"` in a loop -> `@foreach($responses as $response)`, so instead of **unique** `id`s, you have multiple same `id`s

Comment: One method, I'd can think of is, keep your jquery code inside an $('#form1').submit() event and then reference all your variables using $(this).serialize() . But I'd recommend you to add a class to the form rather than id and then using $('.form1')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, replace the `id` on the form with a `class`.

```
<form action="..." method="post" class="commentForm">
<input type="text" name="reply" value="" placeholder="Reply">
<input type="hidden" name="response_id" value="{{$response->id}}">
<input type="submit" name="" value="reply">
</form>
```

Then register a submit-event handler on the forms to make the ajax call. Inside the event handler callback, `this` refers to the form being submitted. You can use that to get the values of the inputs for that form.

```
$('.commentForm').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var $form = $(this);
    var formData = {
        answer     : $form.find('input[name=answer]').val(),
        reply      : $form.find('input[name=reply]').val(),
        response_id: $form.find('input[name=response_id]').val()
    };

    // Make the ajax call here.
});
```

However, you should be able to skip putting together the `formData` object, and use the following for your ajax call:

```
data: $(form).serialize(),
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is looping and creating multiple forms with same name of textboxes, so jquery cannot recognize type='name' are you specifying when your write $('input[name=answer]').val();

So I would suggest you add id to all 3 input tags. For each loop all 3 tags should have the same id. Then you can recognize them individually.