# Send form elements and array through $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I need to pass through $.ajax() method some form elements and an array too. How can i send serialize and array by ajax?

my code bellow:

```js
function loadgraficosajax(){
  var arr = ['331234','142323','327767'];
  
     var data = $('#p-form').serialize;
  
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/page/show",
            data: data,
            dataType : 'html',
            success: function (msg) {
                $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
                    $('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');

                    $(document).off('ajaxComplete').off('ajaxSend');
                    $('#addajax').html(msg);
                 });
            }
        });
 }
```

Comment: var data = {arr,$('#p-form').serialize}

Comment: Welcome, @ikk1. This question seems to already have been [asked and answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32484972/jquery-ajax-form-array-submit) in a [variety of ways](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+ajax+form+array). Remember to search and research before creating your own question. See: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Hello @gfullam! My question is a little different. i need to pass elements and array through a unique ajax request. Sorry if i miss some answers, but i searched a lot before this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) is a method in jQuery, not a property, so you should call it in this way:

```
var data = $('#p-form').serialize();
```

and to pass your array you need to use [`param`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/) method and modify your array to be inside Object, where array name is object property:

```
var arr = { arr: ['331234','142323','327767'] };
var data = $('#p-form').serialize();
data += '&' + $.param( arr );
```

`param` will transform your object to serialised string:

```
console.log($.param( arr )); // "arr[]=331234&arr[]=142323&arr[]=327767"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var formData = new FormData($('#p-form')[0]);

 var arr = ['331234','142323','327767'];

 // append array to formData
 formData.append('arr',JSON.stringify(arr));

 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "/page/show",
     data: formData,
     success:.....
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 0):

You could bundle the two items together in a stringified object which you can send:

```
function loadgraficosajax(){
    var arr = ['331234','142323','327767'];

    var data = $('#p-form').serialize();

    var request = {
        array: arr,
        elements: data
    }

    var data = JSON.stringify(request);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/page/show",
        data: data,
        dataType : 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            $(document).ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings) {
                $('.has-error').removeClass('has-error');

                $(document).off('ajaxComplete').off('ajaxSend');
                $('#addajax').html(msg);
             });
        }
    });
}
```